# Regex for Java SimpleDateFormat pattern (could be specific for birth)

Tags: java, regex, simpledateformat, date

What is a good regex fo Java `SimpleDateFormat` pattern?

Story: I have problem with setting eclipse birth date format patter with DateTimeFormatValue, no exceptions(feedback form QA only).
So, the eclipse birt by it's documentation says that they do support SimpleDateFormat, as because pattern in my application is predefined by user unput, I need some regex check for.. checking only right symbols just no enough. (`"^[y|M|m|h|G|z|s|d|(at)|(aaa)|E|\\.|\\:|\\'|\\/|\\,|\\ ]*$"`)

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't you have to escape the back slashes?

Comment: it`s just a specification of special symbols like ` and / and ,

Comment: Doctor is right, I think. You do have to escape backslashes since according to the Pattern javadoc, _"Backslashes within string literals in Java source code are interpreted as required by the Java Language Specification as either Unicode escapes or other character escapes. **It is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals that represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation by the Java bytecode compiler.**_

Answer (score 1):

I would, if possible, not solve this in a single Regex. You should split the user's input. Eg: `YYYY.mm.DD` split into `[YYYY],[.],[mm],[.],[DD]`.
Now you may check each group if its valid for your purpose. 
As you speak of Year of birth, you would not allow the `hh:mm.ss` or Day of year etc.

This allows you to give the user a response, e.g.: "Year definition is  missing" or "Hours are not allowed".